# Windows 7 screensaver won't activate if set at too many minutes

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

On my Windows 7 PC, if I set the screensaver to activate at 10 minutes or more, then it won't activate. But if I set it to 5 minutes or less, then it will activate.

What could be the problem? How can I find out what's causing this, so that I can set the screensaver to activate at any minute I set?

**Edit:** So I notice that if I turn off my Logitech M525 wireless mouse, then the screensaver activates just fine. I'm using the default Windows 7 drivers for the mouse, and Logitech doesn't seem to have any drivers specifically for this mouse, so I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: Please try this Steps: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-0-screensaver-wont-activate/9d84d474-0cce-425c-bed0-dd3fb4dad29e

Comment: The problem seems to be my wireless mouse. I have a Logitech M525. I just use the default Windows drivers. Logitech themselves don't really have drivers for this mouse. I'm not sure what I can do to fix this.

Comment: Try Logitech Unifying Software: http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/mouse-m525c#download

Comment: I already have the Unifying Software and SetPoint installed, but that didn't help.